# Powershell foreach loop with additional variable and break

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, iteration, break

I am still new to powershell, right now I study `foreach` with `break`, I understand the concept, but when it combined with additional variable and `break`; it confuses me, here is the code:

```
$i=0
$varZ = (10,20,30,40)
foreach ($var in $varZ)
{
    $i++
    if ($var -eq 30)
    {
        break
    }
}
Write-Host "30 was found in array position $i"
```

the result I get showing that variable `$i` = 3, where `$var` = 30
but what confuses me, as I understand `$i` starts with 0 and there is an array `$varZ` (10,20,30,40), as I understand when `$i` = 0 `$var` = 10, hence `$i` = 3 `$var` = 40? please correct me and help me understand this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing $i before you do your conditional check; whereas; it should be done after your break statement.  Although $i is set to 0 before you begin your loop, you immediately increment by 1 with your statement $i++; thus, when $var is 10, $i which was 0 not become 0+1=1 and so forth.